# How to use ajax request to get data from controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajax-request

i am sort of new to ajax .

i am trying to get data from my a method in my controller, i have written the ajax code but does not seem to do the job(not pulling data from controller) maybe i am missing something either in the controller of the ajax request.

i have two dropdowns, i  am trying to populate a dropdown box based on the selection of another dropdown, I am trying to correct data from a method in my controller which I don't know how to.

i would really appreciate some guidance or help on this matter

thank you

```
 public ActionResult ptdrFilter(int id)
    {
        //IUnitOfWork uow = DataAccess.GetUnitOfWork();
        using (ManageProductTemplate ptLogic = new ManageProductTemplate(ref uow))
        {
            List<ProductTemplate> currentpt = ptLogic.GetBy(x => x.ProductTemplateID == id);

            List<string> pt = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in currentpt)
            {
                pt.Add(item.DistributionRule.Name);

            }
            return Json(new {

                pt


            } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

 function drFilter() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "json",
        data: {id: 1},
        url:"/ptdrFilter/",
success: function(result) {
    drFilter(result);
}
    });
        var dataInJSONForm = JSON.stringify(sampleData);
        var datainJSObjectForm = JSON.parse(dataInJSONForm);

        $('#dd1').on('change', function (e) {
            var valueChosenInddl2 = $(this).val();
            var options = datainJSObjectForm[valueChosenInddl2];



            var $subselect = $('#subselect');
            $subselect.children().detach();
            for (var property in options) {
                $subselect.append($('<option>', { value: property, text: options[property] }));
```

}

Comment: Be more specific with the problem... What are you wanting to achieve, what is happening? The result will contain an object called `pt`.

Comment: i have edited the question. and yeah it will as pt contains a list of data

Comment: "does not seem to do the job". What _exactly_ is the problem? Where does it fail?

Comment: it does pull the data from the controller

Comment: ok. so it does that. What _doesn't_ it do? You say it's failing but you don't say how. Do you get errors?

Comment: sorry i meant to say that it does not pull the data from the controller and it does not display any errors

Comment: nothing in the browser console / developer tools (F12 in most browsers)? Have you examined the request in the network tab to see what is being sent and what the response is?

Comment: it display these errors:  Create:590 Uncaught ReferenceError: sampleData is not defineddrFilter @ Create:590(anonymous function) @ Create:855
jquery-1.11.1.js:6531 JSON http://localhost:66940/ptdrFilter/ 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of clear problems here:

1)

```
function drFilter() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "json",
    data: {id: 1},
    url:"/ptdrFilter/",
    success: function(result) {
     drFilter(result);
    }
 });
...
```

is going to produce an infinite loop. When the ajax call completes (successfully), it calls drFilter() again, which will immediately make the ajax call again, and so on forever.

2) I think it's failing because the URL is wrong. In the comments you mention a 404 Not Found error - this means it reached the wrong URL. MVC uses URL routing, so it's best to let MVC generate URLs for you. You can do this using a HTML helper, like this:

```
url: @Url.Action("ptdrFilter")
```

Your browser also reported the the "sampleData" variable was not defined. There's nowhere in your posted code that shows this variable being defined or populated before you try to pass it to the JSON.stringify() method. I'm guessing maybe this is testing code that you haven't removed yet.

Comment: thanks i will try and use this method instead.  it is a testing code i have created a variable :  //  var sampleData = { Default: { value1: "text", value2: "text" }, PTDR: { value1: "cal", value2: "cal" }, All: { value1: "lool", value2: "loool" } };  in order to find out if it populated the second dropdown based on the selection of the first drop down.  since i wont be using thee sampledata variable how will the second dropdown be generic populates itself.  sorry about the amount of questionnew to ajax and still learning it

Comment: I can't really answer about how specifically it will populate the other dropdown - you haven't explained or shown enough code for me to give a detailed answer on that. You asked about the ajax problem, which I hope I have solved. I also pointed out another obvious problem because I could see it. If the answer helps you resolve the ajax issue please mark as accepted. If you have a 2nd question please create a new question on SO :-)